# JavaFX Failed to start Application

Tags: java, javafx

I recently created an IntelliJ JavaFX Project with Java 11 and tried to start the template but I got this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=56068:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\jan\Desktop\Programmieren\Java\Other\RaspberryShell\out\production\RaspberryShell -p "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

And like I said IntelliJ created it for me.
Does anyone have an idea?
Edit: I'm using JavaFX 14

Comment: Add the module javafx.fxml?

Comment: The module path (`-p`) is incorrect.  Unlike a classpath, a module path is not a list of .jar files;  it’s a list of directories containing modular jar files.  So, you want `-p "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I found a solution myself. I installed JavaFX11 and selected it as library. Then I added the vm options to the run configuration `(C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib)` but I got another Error. I fixed the problem by changing the path of the javafx sdk to a folder which doesn't need admin permission. (For example in the localappdata)